# How to send email to customer in custom form in existing module?

Tags: customer

*I want send email to customer. i create form on product view page. when clicking on image the form is open in dialogue box. i want send the mail to customer after form submission. please help*

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately I don't have time to write everything down which is in my mind, but I'll try:

1. Your code looks horrible. You shouldn't put everything in the controller, but instead use models for that.
2. You HAVE TO read about sql injection. Your shop can be hacked, because everyone can directly write to your database. NEVER use mysql_query.

   1. because this method is deprecated and buggy
   2. [you always want to use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575160/using-magento-methods-to-write-insert-queries-with-care-for-sql-injection)
3. If you create a new database connection, SOMETHING IS HORRIBLE WRONG. Read the link how to use magentos connection.
4. Don't rely on JS validation, ALWAYS validate server side. JS is the optional part, not server side!

And to answer your real question:
You want to send a transactional email. There are lots of blog posts about it. The question is to broad to copy everything over.

- http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-sending-custom-emails/
- https://www.ashsmith.io/magento1/2014/08/28/custom-transactional-emails-in-magento/

A few final words:
Before you start working with magento, you need to learn how to code (securely) php/mysql. Good luck